# Is ucwords delimiter parameter supported in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, php-5.6

According to [the official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), the PHP `ucwords` function is available for versions **4**, **5**, **7** and supports a `delimiter` parameter which was introduced in versions **5.4.32** and **5.5.16**.

Thus, I expect for the `delimiter` parameter to be available in version **5.6.***.

Experiment shows instead that it is **not available** in version **5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1**. Is this expected behaviour, a bug in the PHP package I am using, or simply a mistake from my part?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It works for me on almost exactly the same version as you: `PHP 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1`. Could you post your code, just to be sure?

Comment: Could you show your experiment?

Comment: according to this,  https://3v4l.org/HmU1K it works fine

Comment: maybe run phpinfo() to verify version currently executed by you script

Comment: See the edit on my answer, I believe that `5.5.9`, being earlier then `5.5.16`, does not have this feature (that was a response to @KhorneHoly , but the comment is removed now)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and answers. I WAS mistaken. I discovered that several versions of PHP are installed on the box, and that WEB is using a different version than CLI, thus my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
<?php

$word = "foo|bar";
echo(ucwords($word, "|"); // Foo|Bar
```

Works as expected in all PHP versions, here's the output: https://3v4l.org/Uf3Ya

Answer (score 1):

You can run a quick test with all the versions you want with docker.

With 5.6 you will get the expected behaviour:

> $ docker run -i php:5.6-cli php -r "echo ucwords('hello|world', '|') . PHP_EOL; "
>   Hello|World

Maybe check with `php --version` what version you are actually calling?

For reference, this is the response for a version that does not have the option:

> docker run -i php:5.3-cli php -r "echo ucwords('hello|world', '|') . PHP_EOL; "
>
> Warning: ucwords() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in Command line code on line 1

The parameter is added, according to the docs:

> 5.4.32, 5.5.16 Added the delimiters parameter.

So in the case of @khorneholy , `5.5.9` would NOT have this feature

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add.

On one of my system `PHP 5.6.30-11+deb.sury.org~trusty+3`, `ucwords()` throws warning:

> Warning: ucwords() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in ...

On  my other system with `PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1`, it works fine.